# python flask uwsgi start job failed to start

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Recently I tried to serve flask application with uwsgi and nginx on ubuntu 14.04. However, some errors occur. Here is my `testblog.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = testblog.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

When I run `uwsgi --ini testblog.ini`, it works fine. But when I `sudo start myproject`, it occurs `start: Job failed to start`. Here is my `/etc/init/myproject.conf`,

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve testblog"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid chester
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/chester/myproject/testblog/venv/bin
chdir /home/chester/myproject/testblog
exec uwsgi --ini testblog.ini
```

The env path and the directory is right. Besides, I have checked `/var/log/upstart/myproject.log`, it does not point any new messages.
So what should I do to fix this problem? Thank you very much.